# October 2015 Community Challenge

Tags: discussion, fun, community-challenge

I don't see one of these yet, so here's the question for the proposals for the October 2015 Community Challenge!

---

It's time to choose a [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) for October 2015.

- Post your challenge as an answer to this question. Feel free to resubmit non-winning ideas from previous months.
- Vote for those answers which interest you.
- At the end-of-day on Wednesday, September 30th, the top-voted post will become the next challenge.

Once the challenge topic is decided, post your solution as a [question on the main site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and tag it with [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge). The challenge runs throughout October (but nothing stops you from posting an entry later on).

Comment: October! Already!?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Mandelbrot Set Fractals

So it seems we started *something* here with [Mandelbrot sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), so the proposal I want to make for October 2015 is to write a programme in your favourite language (or a new one if you're feeling adventurous) that will generate a Mandelbrot set fractal.

At the bare minimum it should be able to generate the entire Mandelbrot region from `x: [-2.5, 1]`, `y: [-1, 1]`.

Optionally it can support zooming and rendering custom regions.

Comment: So this is the *de-facto* challenge, I guess?

Comment: It looks like it, unless we want to push back the October challenge to November.